# Multiple content_for blocks in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

Is there a more elegant way of using multiple `content_for` blocks within `.erb` templates? I have several views that include the following, but I feel that there is a better/cleaner practice.

```
<% content_for :background do %>
white-background
<% end %>
<% content_for :navbar do %>
plain-gradient
<% end %>
<% content_for :push do %>
push
<% end %>
<% content_for :dropzone do %>
application-upload-controller
<% end %>
```